# Save id of post to the new table in Wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress

I created a new table(new_table) in the Database.
I need, when I am adding a new post, id this post will save to my table(new_table.p_id).
How can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the wpdb class's insert method.

First parameter is the table you want to insert data into. The second is an array containing the data in key value pairs.

Hook this into save_post.

```
function wpse_add_new_post_id_to_table( $post_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $post_status = get_post_status( $post_id );

    if ( 'publish' != $post_status )
        return false;

    $wpdb->insert( 'new_table', array( 'p_id' => $post_id ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'wpse_add_new_post_id_to_table' );
```

Further reading:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Thank you, it is working but when I add post or delete post this function working too and save id into db. I want when I add a post this function run and when I delete post its id delete from my table too.

Comment: I have updated my code with a minor improvement. Can you clarify your last comment. I'm not following you.

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand, how can add only id for the post with the post_status = publish, it doesn't work.
function wpse_add_new_post_id_to_table( $post_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
 $status = get_post_status( $post_id );
 $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO r_p_id (p_id) VALUES ('$post_id') WHERE $status = 'publish'");
}

Comment: I can not forbidden for edit that do not add id to the table. I wrote: if ($_GET['post'] == $post_id and $_GET['action']=='edit')
  return false;

Comment: It helped and I add ID of post to my table but id is adding into the my table too, when I edit post with this id. I want ID of post, add to my table only, when I add a post.

Comment: Did you copy my code exactly including my update? wp_insert_post only fires on the creation of a new post.

Comment: Yes but when I edit the post this id saving into the table again.

Comment: It sounds like you still have the save_post action in place. I've tested the code above and it doesn't save again when editing.

Comment: this is my code: function wpse_add_new_post_id_to_table($post_id) {
    global $wpdb;
 $post_status = get_post_status($post_id);
    if ( 'publish' != $post_status )
        return false;

   $wpdb->insert( 'r_p_id', array( 'p_id' => $post_id ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'wpse_add_new_post_id_to_table' );

Answer (score -1):

You use something like this action

```
function insert_id_to_db() {
  global $post;

  $postid = $post->id;

  $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO table(id) VALUES('{$postid }')");

}

add_action('save_post', 'insert_id_to_db');
```

Comment: You're using $wpdb but you haven't added the global so it won't work. $wpdb has more appropriate methods. Your first two lines of the function are redundant when the first argument passed into the function is the post ID.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post